# Need help overriding button styling for slider from external CSS document

Tags: html, css, marketo

I am working on a project where I need to update the external CSS files for a webpage.
The problem is that I need to use a Marketo token to dictate what the new CSS style will be. Tokens do not work in external CSS files; I've tried.

I've been able to do most of this work myself, however, I am stuck at one element: a slider. I want to modify the color of the [slider buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6jg1.png) to be determined by the Marketo tokens. I have tried "rebuilding" the slider section in the webpage html code, but so far no luck.

Any ideas?

This is a time-sensitive project, too.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are trying to override previous css codes. Have you tried the following?

1. background-color: red !important;
2. Putting the link of the css file you want to be valid at the bottom.
3. deleting all the classes of the button related to javascript and adding new classes to style them.

```css
.color{
    color: red;
     color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">Color</div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('.js-a').classList.add('js-b');
document.querySelector('.js-a').classList.remove('js-a');
```

```css
.js-b{
color:blue;
}

.js-a{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-a">Javascript</div>
```

Comment: Hello, can I share the files with you? I don't know what's possible to do.